# CSS child element selection for html changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have two html section:

```
<div id="signin">
  <div class="dialog">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="header">
        <h4>Title</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="phone">
  <div class="dialog">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="header">
        <h4>Title</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I try to change the h4 element's html with this:

```
$("#signin > .dialog > .content > .header > h4").html("Sign In");
```

or

```
$("#signin > h4").html("Sign In");
```

but it didn't worked, any idea?

Comment: your first code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/blonfu/xeo0wq48/  The second doesn't works because h4 isn't child of `#signin`, is descendant but not child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `>` from your selector and wrap your code in `$(function() { ... });` i.e code should execute when content is fully loaded and ready to be manipulated:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#signin h4").html("Sign In");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="signin">
  <div class="dialog">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="header">
        <h4>Title</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="phone">
  <div class="dialog">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="header">
        <h4>Title</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#signin").find('h4').html("Sign In");
//$("#signin > .dialog > .content > .header > h4").html("Sign In");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="signin">
  <div class="dialog">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="header">
        <h4>Title</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="phone">
  <div class="dialog">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="header">
        <h4>Title</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

1. Use [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

> Description: Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$("#signin > .dialog > .content > .header > h4").html("Sign In");` in this script `>` means 1st child element but in your html `h4` is 4th child element of `#signin` so you need to use like this

```
$("#signin h4")
```

Or use `.find()` method

```
$("#signin").find('h4');
```